# Preview issue for non System Admin users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, permissions, slds, fileupload

I am using Lighting:fileCard in the aura component and the System admin can see the preview of the file but not the other user with different Profile.

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:fileCard fileId="069XXXXXXXXXXXX" description="Sample Description"/>
</aura:component>
```

Is there any permission that needs to be enabled to preview content/Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether they have access to Files.

1.From Setup, enter User Profiles in the Quick Find box, and select Profiles.
2.Click Edit next to the user profile you want to change.
3.In the Administrative Permissions section, enable or disable  Select Files from Salesforce checkbox, and click Save.

Comment: I have enabled that permission but it's still not working. @Prathyusha

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post after having a similar issue and after troubleshooting was able to determine that the component visibility issue because the User Profile was lacking permission on the Apex Class used referenced as controller of the Lightning Component. Not sure if that is your issue but figured I would let you know in case it was!